# Regular expression for valid signature names

Tags: c#, regex

I having the following regexp for validating the function name:

```
([a-zA-Z]\w+)[^\w]
```

This regular expression is capable of avoiding special characters except underscore but if we put special characters in the beginning then this expression can't validate.

So can you make it work little better?

thanks in adv

Comment: A good start is the C# language spec to ensure that the regex matches the actual spec: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664670(VS.71).aspx.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I find your question and comments hard to parse. Could you edit your question and post some sample texts that you want the regex to validate, and some that you want the regex to reject?

Comment: Where does Java come into this?

Answer (score 4):

You need to match from the beginning to the end of the whole function name:

```
^([a-zA-Z]\w+)[^\w]$
```

Comment: ([a-zA-Z]\w+)[^\w] this is working fine but if we have any spcl char at beginning then only it is not working

Comment: @Karaszi The actual spec is more complex than that: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664670\(VS.71\).aspx.

Comment: I thought so, but they were happy with the previous regexp.

Comment: @Karaszi Sure, I guess the answer is meant to be correct for all people that want to know, rather than just for the narrow use of the OP.

Comment: @chibacity: actually we don't know what they want. Maybe they want to narrow the possible names because of a coding standard. but yes, you're right about the correctness.

Comment: simple a function name can not have any spcl char except _ . my reg exp is working fine but if we insert spcl chars initially then it is not working.

Comment: @Abhishek: in the OP pls! and please post the corresponding code as well.

Answer (score 0):

Following the C# language specification:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664670(VS.71).aspx

The following regex will handle special cases of '_' and '@', plus validate non ASCII letters i.e. validates unicode identifiers.

```
[Test]
public void ValidateIdentifiers()
{
  Regex regex = new Regex(
  @"^@?_*[\p{Ll}\p{Lu}\p{Lt}\p{Lo}\p{Nd}\p{Nl}\p{Mn}\p{Mc}\p{Cf}\p{Pc}\p{Lm}]*$");

  Assert.That(regex.IsMatch("Bling"),   Is.True);
  Assert.That(regex.IsMatch("@_Bling"), Is.True);
  Assert.That(regex.IsMatch("_Bling"), Is.True);
  Assert.That(regex.IsMatch("__Bling"), Is.True);
  Assert.That(regex.IsMatch("_Bling_Bling"), Is.True);
  Assert.That(regex.IsMatch("السياحى"), Is.True);
  Assert.That(regex.IsMatch("_@Bling"), Is.False);
}
```

Comment: @Abhishek Am I missing something in your question? The above should validate C# function names according to the official C# language specification.

Answer (score -1):

Right now the expression is saying: one letter followed by one or more letter/numbers/underscores, followed by a non-word character. So by design, the fact that it won't validate if you start with a special character is correct.

If you want to allow for the _ as the first letter, change to:

```
(\w+)[^\w]
```